# Send php code via ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to make an ajax request with jquery, but I'm getting 403 Forbidden error each time I'm sending php functions. An example of what I need is this stackoverflow comment input which accepts source code also.

What I've done:

**PHP**

```
class Error {
  public function __construct() {
    // etc
  }

  public function comment($error_id, $content) {

    if(!$this->user->loged)
      return false;

    $error_id = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($error_id);
    if(!is_numeric($error_id))
      return false;

    $this->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO comments 
                          VALUES (NULL, '" . $error_id . "', '" . $this->user->user_id . "', '" . $content . "', NULL)");
    return $this->mysqli->insert_id;

  }
}
```

where `$content` is escaped using `escapeString` function inside `Common` class:

```
public function escapeString($text) {
  return htmlspecialchars($this->mysqli->real_escape_string($text));
}
```

**my JS is:**

```
$('div.left-content').on('click','form.comment input[type=button]',function(){

        $but = $(this);

        if(!erori.user.loged) {

            showTooltip($but, 'Trebuie să fii autentificat pentru a putea comenta!');

            return false;
        }

        if($but.prev('textarea').val() == $but.prev('textarea').data("text") || $but.prev('textarea').val().trim() == '') {

            showTooltip($but, 'Completează câmpul de text pentru a putea trimite comentariul!');

            return false;
        }

        if($but.prev('textarea').hasClass('disabled'))
            return false;

        $but.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $but.prev('textarea').addClass('disabled');

        $.post(
            $but.parent().attr('action'),
            $but.parent().serialize(),
            function(data){
                if(data.content) {
                    $('<div class="comment"></div>').html(data.content).insertBefore($but.parent().parent());
                    if($but.prev('textarea').hasClass('disabled'))
                        $but.prev('textarea').val('').trigger('blur').animate({height: '20px'}, 300);
                    $but.prev('textarea').removeClass('disabled');
                }

                $but.removeAttr('disabled');

            },
            'json')
        .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if(errorThrown == 'Forbidden') {
                showTooltip($but, 'Comentariul nu a putut fi trimis!<br />Dacă vrei să trimiți sursă de cod folosește <strong>` cod sursă `</strong>!');

                $but.prev('textarea').removeClass('disabled');
                $but.removeAttr('disabled');

                return false;
            }
        })                                                         
    });
```

**and the action code is:**

```
$error = new Error($mysqli, $user);

$content = $common->escapeString($_POST['error_comment']);

$comment_id = $error->comment($_POST['error_id'], $content);
```

How to escape the source code before sending it to server, for not getting back this 403 Forbidden error?

What I'm trying to say is that if I'm trying to comment for example: `This is my comment with <?php $sql = mysql_query(); ?>` the server is throwing 403 error code!

Comment: And is it everything ok, if you write comment without php-code?

Comment: yes.. everything is ok.. even if I've write js, css or some php code.. everything is ok.. but when trying to send some php function it returns that 403 error

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really filter your code before sending, because user can just turn off javascript and send code to you directly, skipping any clientside filtering.

And 403 error - it's a "rights" error, so you need to fix headers or right for php-file.

Comment: Right.. good point of view.. then which will be the solution on server-side? for not evaluating the code...

Comment: why not to expand "escapeString($text)" and put there other filters you need?

Comment: which are those filters? :) this is what I need .. but I don't know those filters

Comment: actually, you can just do str_replace for <? and <?php ;)